# Apache rewrite , multiple domains single Document root

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a website lets say www.xyz.com at /home/xyz/public_html as document root, it has a bunch of rewrite rules. Now I want to point www.abc.com to same document root and use the same rewrite rules for www.abc.com.

I would redirect www.xyz.com to www.abc.com using rewrite but I dont want to change the url being displayed to the visitors.

Is there any solution to redirect the domain and not display but not display the redirected url ?

Also i want to use the existing rewrite rules after redirection to xyz.com

The rewrite rules have the domain name hardcoded, i want to generalize rewrite rules.

eg. 
`RewriteCond     %{SERVER_NAME}  ^xyz.com$
RewriteRule     ^/(.*)          http://www.xyz.com/$1       [L,R]`

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the central configuration, you are looking for [`ServerAlias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#serveralias).

> The ServerAlias directive sets the alternate names for a host, for use with name-based virtual hosts.
>
> ```
> <VirtualHost *>
> ServerName server.domain.com
> ServerAlias server server2.domain.com server2
> # ...
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

if you *don't* have access to the central configuration, but only to `.htaccess` files, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: I thought of using server Alias , but then there are rewrite rules like :    
`RewriteCond     %{SERVER_NAME}  ^xyz.com$
RewriteRule     ^/(.*)          http://www.xyz.com/$1

RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT}  !^443$
RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}    ^(www\.)?(.*)\.xyz              [NC]  
RewriteCond     %2              !^www                           [NC]
#RewriteRule     ^/?(.*)   https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1   [R]
RewriteRule     ^/(.*)     /members/index.php/$1`

In order to do that, I might first have to generalize this rewrite. How can i make the above rules work for any domain ? 

Thanks

Comment: This is my first time in stackoverflow, so please excuse my formatting, they have the domain name coded in the rewrite rules.

Comment: @user ah, right. I see. I'm not sure how to make that generic - do edit that information into your question